# How to use AfterAdvice Interface in java

Tags: spring, aop, aspect

I am new to spring.I know that `AfterAdvice` will cause the after method to execute whether target method completes or exits with exception, but i am not able to find out any example for it.

As `AfterAdvice` is a marker interface, I don't know which method i need to define in it's implementation class.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to implement those interfaces directly. Instead, you use either

1. Use `@After` annotation to mark the method you want to it to be called.
2. Use spring xml bean configuration `aop:advice` to declare an after advice method

However, if you choose to use ProxyFactoryBean

As you indicate that you want to use ProxyFactoryBean, you can declare the xml like this

```xml
<bean id="interceptor"
   class="yourimplementation">
</bean>
<bean id="setterAdvisor"
   class="org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="advice">
        <ref bean="interceptor"/>
    </property>
    <property name="patterns">
        <list>
            <value>.*set.*</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="person"
    class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="com.mycompany.Person"/>
    <property name="target" ref="personTarget"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>setterAdvisor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

For the java implementation, there is no use to implement `Advice` interface. You should either implement `ThrowingAdvice` or `AfterReturningAdvice`. Refer to [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html) for more info.

For more information, you can refer to a [couple](http://www.journaldev.com/2583/spring-aop-example-tutorial-aspect-advice-pointcut-joinpoint-annotations-xml-configuration) [tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) [guides](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/aspect-oriented-programming-spring-aop.html) on Spring AOP and play around with it to get a sense.

Comment: I want to use it via spring xml configuration. Can you please provide a link for the examples as I am getting the example only for AfterReturning Advice instead on AfterAdvice.

Comment: I am not using aop namespaces. I am using basic xml configurations with ProxyFactoryBean.

Comment: Hi Nat, Thanks for your detailed explaination but my Query was that We can use the AfterAdvice using annotation So is there any way that we can also use AfterAdvice(Not AfterReturningAdvice) using xml Configuration.